# Where there any other Master who didn't know their Servant's identity from the start?

Tags: fate-series

In *Fate/Zero* it seems to be implied that all the Masters, from the moment they started working with them, knew the identity of their Servants.

i known however that

- in *Fate/Stay Night*

  - Shirou didn't learn Saber's identity until much later because it was feared that if he was captured he wouldn't be able to defend against mind reading magic
  - Rin didn't learn Archer's at first because the summoning went wrong and messed up his memories however he continued to withhold it when he did remember who he was
- in *Fate/Extra*

  - Hakuno didn't know the identity of his/her Saber, Archer or Caster until the final couple of weeks but i am not sure how many of the Masters they faced off knew their Servant's Identities at the start (though i get the feeling Rin, Leo and Rani knew)

so in all the Grail Wars (Fuyuki (*Fate/Stay Night*), Snowfield (*Fate/Strange Fake*), Moon Cell (*Fate/Extra*), Trifas (*Fate/Apocrypha*), Tokyo (*Fate/Prototype*), Caubac Alcatraz's Labyrinth (*Fate/Labyrinth*) etc.) where there any other Master who didn't know their Servant's identity at the beginning? if not at all?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want them to be unknown at the beginning, then in Fate/Zero Uryuu did not know who [his Caster](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Caster_(Fate/Zero)) ("Bluebeard") was.  Much like Shirou, Uryuu was not even aware that he was summoning a servant until Bluebeard showed up.  Unlike Shirou, he wasn't even aware that magic really existed.  He was just doing the ritual in the occult book he had for the fun of it.

While Bluebeard tells Uryuu his nickname of "Bluebeard" right away, it is unclear if Uryuu knows who this refers to.  I'm not sure if it is ever mentioned if Uryuu ever learned the true identity of his Servant.  They had a weird relationship, with Uryuu largely seeing Bluebeard as a kindred spirit and teacher, and they never really cared about the formalities of the war or what they were "supposed" to be doing in it.  They were definitely on good enough terms for Bluebeard to share the information, but they simply may not have cared about it.